# Nativescript: Transferring mp3 files with Sidekick

Tags: nativescript

I'm making a simple app that uses nativescript-audio and I want to play some mp3 samples in the app. The problem is, when I click "Run on Device" in Sidekick, it doesn't transfer any mp3 files I included in the app folder (and therefore I can't play it). What is weird is that if I just change the extension of the file (for example to .jpg), the transfer works fine (and I can even play that file as if it was mp3).

So, just to exemplify the problem, if I use this code, it doesn't work:

```
const audio = require('nativescript-audio');
const player = new audio.TNSPlayer();
const playerOptions = {
  audioFile: '~/audio/myfile.mp3',
  loop: false
};
```

But if I just rename "myfile.mp3" to "myfile.jpg", change the code like this:

```
...
audioFile: '~/audio/myfile.jpg',
...
```

and then rebuild the app, it works just fine and plays the sample that was originally stored in myfile.mp3 and is now stored in myfile.jpg.

Using file-system I can also detect the .jpg file is present but .mp3 is not.

What I want to ask is whether Sidekick looks only for certain file extensions and ignores the others during build, and whether I can change the "watched file extensions" setting.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets that would show your attempts? That would help.

Comment: I will enclose the code I use to play the mp3s in the app but I feel it is irrelevant in this case. The code works just fine when the file I want to play is actually present. The problem is that for some reason Sidekick doesn't transfer the file if it has the extension .mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running with webpack, the default webpack configuration will copy only fonts and images (JPEG / PNG etc.,) along with your source code. If you have any other files to be copied modify the copy plugin configurations inside `webpack.config.js` something like,

```
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: "fonts/**" },
            { from: "songs/**" },
            { from: "**/*.jpg" },
            { from: "**/*.png" },
            { from: "**/*.png" },
        ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem and also revealed to me that I must learn more about nativescript building process. :)